# Windows 10 say 32-bits with 64-bits processor?

Tags: windows-10, cpu, 64-bit

I'm certain that my processor is 64-bits, but for some reason windows is saying that it is 32-bits. now I have 1GB less for use

[image: Screenshot]

Here is my processor

https://ark.intel.com/products/72056/Intel-Core-i5-3230M-Processor-3M-Cache-up-to-3_20-GHz-BGA

I have 4GB (2.66 usable)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you installed the 32 bit version of Windows instead of the 64 bit version.
The only way to fix this is to install the correct Windows version.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: Download the media creation tool from microsoft's website, run it, select "create installation media". Next you can pick if you want 32 or 64 bit. Select 64 bit there. Lastly you can tell the program if you want to create a USB Stick or DVD. But before you do all of this you should make sure that you have a license key that is valid for that version.

Comment: However if your computer only has 4GB of Ram, you may not profit from switching to 64bit.

Answer (score 2):

**You have installed 32-bit Windows on 64-bit CPU.**

Windows comes in 32-bit and 64-bit versions. 64-bit Windows runs only on 64-bit CPUs, but 32-bit Windows can be successfully installed both on 32-bit and 64-bit CPUs.

It has some advantages, eg. it can run old DOS-era 16-bit programs. You probably don't need this. The most significant disadvantage is lack of support for 4 GB of RAM (exact amount available depends on hardware).